# How to hide all post's having certain labels on home page in Google Blogger?

Tags: xml, label, blogs, blogger, posts

Let's consider, "Coding", "Technical","Diary" are some labels on blog and I do not want to display all "diary" label's posts on homepage (with my rest of the label post's) so what I want to do ?
I want that XML code to hide post's with some labels from homepage ! [I search uncountable times same thing on search engines like yahoo,google,yandex,etc but I didn't got anything, [ hope blogger/xml community should help !]

[check image to view label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km8Wf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Search for the following emphasised (bold) code in your template (Template - Edit HTML)

```
....
<div class='post-outer'>
<b:include data='post' name='post'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "static_page"'> 
....
```

Replace that line (aka `<b:include data='post' name='post'/>` ) with

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
        <b:if cond='data:label.isLast == "true"'>
            <b:if cond='data:label.name != "LabelYouWantToHide"'>
                <b:include data='post' name='post' />
            </b:if>
        </b:if>
    </b:loop>
<b:else/>
    <b:include data='post' name='post' />
</b:if>
```

Replace `LabelYouWantToHide` with the real label name you want hidden from the homepage. Also for the above code to work correctly, make sure the posts that you want to hide only has **1 label** on them.

Another thing to remember is that every post in your blog (at least the ones on the homepage) should have a label otherwise they would not be visible on the homepage because the `b:loop` statement wouldn't be executed for them

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for answer. I resolved this by creating new blog (with same design) and redirecting after clicking on certain label.

Comment: I tried your code on this site https://www.intelligentindia.in/ but then i cannot have multiple  labels for single blogger post. If i add more than one label on a single post it will show the post multiple times on home page. Is there any other way to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: @user3223016 I suggest trying the example present here to implement something like that - http://template-data.blogspot.com/p/bwith.html