# How to hide posts in a label from the home page Blogger

Tags: xml, blogger

I have some posts that are just javascript, and when it appears on the home page the whole script is shown, I want posts containing the "Pasta" label to be hidden from the home page.

**I tried to replace this:** `<b:include data='post' name='post'/>`
**For this:**

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
        <b:if cond='data:label.isLast == "true"'>
            <b:if cond='data:label.name != "LabelYouWantToHide"'>
                <b:include data='post' name='post' />
            </b:if>
        </b:if>
    </b:loop>
<b:else/>
    <b:include data='post' name='post' />
</b:if>
```

[THE ABOVE CODE WAS FOUND IN THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492162/how-to-hide-all-posts-having-certain-labels-on-home-page-in-google-blogger)

**And I've also tried the content on [this page](http://template-data.blogspot.com/p/bwith.html).**

```
    <b:with var='posts'
            value='data:posts filter
                   (p => p.labels none
                         (l => l.name == "hide-me"))'>
    </b:with>
```

But this hides the post even in the page of the post itself
I think something in my template is preventing it from working, but I could not identify

**My test blog [here](http://testenextdark.blogspot.com)**
**Template code [here](https://pastebin.com/SPDd2NFq)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `<b:include data='post' name='post'/>` and replace it with these lines:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
  <b:if cond='data:post.labels none ( l => l.name == "Pasta" )'>
    <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
  </b:if>
  <b:else/>
  <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
</b:if>
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that creates empty white spaces in the home page. So it does not really hide the post space but just what's inside the post space. Is there any new method to totally hide the post space in home page? Thnx