# delete post from home page

Tags: xml, label, blogger, blogs

I am following up on this post:

[How to hide all post's having certain labels on home page in Google Blogger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492162/how-to-hide-all-posts-having-certain-labels-on-home-page-in-google-blogger).

I test out the suggested solution to my post. I want to remove "tips" from the home page. "Tips" doesn't have any image.

So, I deleted all the suggested codes:

```
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
          <b:include data='post' name='comment_picker'/>
        </b:if>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
          <b:include data='post' name='comment_picker'/>
        </b:if>

and replace them with the recommended solution: 

<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
        <b:if cond='data:label.isLast == "true"'>
            <b:if cond='data:label.name != "tips"'>
                <b:include data='post' name='post' />
            </b:if>
        </b:if>
    </b:loop>
<b:else/>
    <b:include data='post' name='post' />
</b:if>

After the update, all my posts disappear from the homepage.

How can remove label "tips" from not appearing on the homepage.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace the line `<b:include data='post' name='post' />` not `<b:include data='post' name='comment_picker'/>`

Also, "tips" != "Tips"

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out my errors. It worked. However, on the home page, post I don't want to show leaves a trace. As a result, there's a gap in between posts. See the home page. https://lamnewsite.blogspot.com/

Comment: You are welcome, that happened because of the element `<div class="post-outer">` around your last code, if you can include it inside `b:if` or show blog1 widget code here to suggest another way.

Comment: Here's my updated question, which show the code for <div class> and the blog1 widget. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130262/removing-trace-of-hidden-post-on-home-page