# removing trace of hidden post on home page

Tags: xml, label, blogger

I am following up on the solution in the below post: [delete post from home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120391/delete-post-from-home-page)

The solution worked. But the hidden post leave a trace on the home page, which I described in the comment section.

It was recommended that I post another question, showing the code, which caused the problem.

"...that happened because of the element  around your last code, if you can include it inside b:if or show blog1 widget code here to suggest another way."

Below is the copy of the widget "Blog1".

How can I edit my  to remove the label from showing blank.

The blog is: https://lamnewsite.blogspot.com/

```
<b:widget id='Blog1' locked='false' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog' version='1'>
    <b:widget-settings>
      <b:widget-setting name='showDateHeader'>true</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='style.textcolor'>#000000</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showShareButtons'>true</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='authorLabel'>By</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showCommentLink'>true</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='style.urlcolor'>#008000</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showAuthor'>false</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='disableGooglePlusShare'>true</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='style.linkcolor'>#0000ff</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='style.unittype'>TextAndImage</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='style.bgcolor'>#ffffff</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showAuthorProfile'>false</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='style.layout'>1x1</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showLabels'>true</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showLocation'>true</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showTimestamp'>true</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='postsPerAd'>1</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showBacklinks'>false</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='style.bordercolor'>#ffffff</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showInlineAds'>false</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showReactions'>false</b:widget-setting>
    </b:widget-settings>
    <b:includable id='main' var='top'>
  <b:if cond='!data:mobile'>
    <!-- posts -->
<div class='blog-posts hfeed'>

 <b:include data='top' name='status-message'/>

 <data:defaultAdStart/>
 <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
<div class='post-outer'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
        <b:if cond='data:label.isLast == &quot;true&quot;'>
            <b:if cond='data:label.name != &quot;tips&quot;'>
                <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
            </b:if>
        </b:if>
    </b:loop>
<b:else/>
    <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
</b:if>
   </div>
    <b:if cond='data:post.includeAd'>
     <b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'>
     <data:defaultAdEnd/>
     <b:else/>
     <data:adEnd/>
     </b:if>
      <div class='inline-ad'>
       <data:adCode/>
      </div>
      <data:adStart/>
    </b:if>
 </b:loop>
 <data:adEnd/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the tag `<div class='post-outer'>` inside `b:if` statement to avoid showing empty tag.

Here is the code:

```
<b:widget id='Blog1' locked='false' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog' version='1'>
    <b:widget-settings>
      <b:widget-setting name='showDateHeader'>true</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='style.textcolor'>#000000</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showShareButtons'>true</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='authorLabel'>By</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showCommentLink'>true</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='style.urlcolor'>#008000</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showAuthor'>false</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='disableGooglePlusShare'>true</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='style.linkcolor'>#0000ff</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='style.unittype'>TextAndImage</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='style.bgcolor'>#ffffff</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showAuthorProfile'>false</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='style.layout'>1x1</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showLabels'>true</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showLocation'>true</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showTimestamp'>true</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='postsPerAd'>1</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showBacklinks'>false</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='style.bordercolor'>#ffffff</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showInlineAds'>false</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showReactions'>false</b:widget-setting>
    </b:widget-settings>
    <b:includable id='main' var='top'>
  <b:if cond='!data:mobile'>
    <!-- posts -->
<div class='blog-posts hfeed'>

 <b:include data='top' name='status-message'/>

 <data:defaultAdStart/>
 <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>

<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>

    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
        <b:if cond='data:label.isLast == &quot;true&quot;'>
            <b:if cond='data:label.name != &quot;tips&quot;'>
              <div class='post-outer'>
                <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
              </div>
            </b:if>
        </b:if>
    </b:loop>

<b:else/>
  <div class='post-outer'>
    <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
  </div>
</b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:post.includeAd'>
     <b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'>
     <data:defaultAdEnd/>
     <b:else/>
     <data:adEnd/>
     </b:if>
      <div class='inline-ad'>
       <data:adCode/>
      </div>
      <data:adStart/>
    </b:if>
 </b:loop>
 <data:adEnd/>
</div>
```

Comment: I replace my code with yours. Nothing changes. I notice you already have  <b:includable id='main' var='top'> at end of widget-settings.  Do I need to add another one?